# Must every sidrah begin at the start of a parsha? (Rashi on Breishit 47:28)

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torah-reading, safrus, vayechi

Rashi on Genesis 47:28 (excerpt)

**ויחי יעקב** לָמָּה פָּרָשָׁה זוֹ סְתוּמָה?

ויחי יעקב AND JACOB LIVED — Why is this section (weekly reading) totally closed?

**Explanation for novices:** The Torah scroll is written using paragraphs, which in this terminology is called a *parsha*. Common terminology uses the term "parsha' to refer to the weekly Torah reading. This is the term Rash"i is using, here.

Usually, the weekly Torah reading begins at the start of a new paragraph. Parshat *Vayechi* is the only exception that does not. In the Torah, all you see is a space of one letter between the end of the previous weekly reading (*Vayigash*) and the start of *Vayechi*.

I can understand that, perhaps, Rash"i is seeing a common pattern that all other readings began at the start of a paragraph, and this seems unusual. However, Rash"i feels a need to explain this anomaly.

Perhaps the incentive to decide where the weekly reading ends happens to make sense to complete a story, law, or some other meaningful unit, and it just happens to end at a paragraph. (I.e., it's incidental.) Maybe, this location was the most logical meaningful place to end *Vayigash*. Who or what dictated the notion that a weekly reading must end at the end of a paragraph (or that a reading should start at the beginning of one?)

Comment: Maybe the fact that every other _sedra_ besides this one starts at the beginning of a _parsha_?

Comment: @Daniel The question was, is this the significant reason for the break or is it an artifact of a different reaqn?

Comment: @sabbahillel The question was "Who or what dictated the notion that a weekly reading must end at the end of a paragraph (or that a reading should start at the beginning of one?)"

Comment: Ta'anis reading also starts in the middle... any other exceptions?

Comment: @DannySchoemann My question asks specifically about the weekly (Shabbat) readings. Until you mentioned it, I believe that even all other readings except for Ta'anit, also begin at the start of a parsha. Perhaps, you want to ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @DanF, let's first see if you get an answer to the _easier_ question.

Comment: The Siftei Chachamim says that this is actually an "invisible" parsha break that the mesorah is to write as just one letter.  I have no idea if anyone else says this.  Potential nafka minah: if there's a natural disaster during the week of Vayigash and the community is making it up during Vaychi, can you end an aliyah within 2 pesukim of the end of Vayigash?

Comment: To expand on @Heshy’s point. According to the Siftei Chachamim, when Rashi says ‘parsha zo’ he is not referring to the entire sidrah of vayechi, but rather to the small parsha at the start of the sidrah. In which case the motivation for the question changes - it’s not that Rashi implies that a sidrah must start at the beginning of a parsha. Rather, every sidrah, __including__ __vayechi__ happens to start with a new parsha. Is that significant?

Comment: @Heshy Your *nafka minah* is fascinating. It may warrant a separate question, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Berachot 12a**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=12b&format=pdf)

> גמירי כל פרשה דפסקה משה רבינו פסקינן דלא פסקה משה רבינו לא פסקינן
>
> We have a tradition that every section which our master, Moses, has
>   divided off we may divide off, but that which our master, Moses, has
>   not divided off, we may not divide off. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

Comment: So how come we can do so when it comes to vayigash/vayechi?

Comment: @JoelK That wasn't the question in this post, so my answer was not addressing that. However, the general question of how we can read certain passages that do not have parsha breaks has been discussed by various poskim. The first point is that though it is stated in the Gemara, the Rambam, Tur, Shulchan Aruch, etc. all do not codify this. Also, various exceptions have been suggested. A simple one is that of R. Chaim Berlin (Shu"t Nishmas Chaim #9) that a new topic has the same status as  a parsha break.

Comment: But doesn’t the fact that we seem to often ignore this rule mean that it is less likely to be the reason for splitting sidrot at a new parashah?

Comment: Hi Alex. This isn't answering my question. My question focuses on the weekly Torah reading. Did you understand my usage of *parsha* vs. *sidrah*? Maybe that's still confusing? I'm asking if there's a rule that requires the weekly Torah reading to start at the beginning of a parsha.

Comment: @DanF My answer addresses the weekly Torah reading. You ask why the weekly reading should start/end at the beginning of a parsha. My answer is that the Talmud says that we are not allowed to break up the Torah in a way other than how Moshe did, i.e. the parsha breaks.

Comment: @JoelK It could be less likely, but if you're looking for a reason, and the Talmud clearly states an applicable rule, then it would make sense that that has something to do with it, and the exceptions are exceptions.

Comment: Alex. Again - I think we are confusing terminology. I think in Berachot on that page, the term "parsha" means paragraph, not a weekly Torah reading. I know that the terms changed over time. Can you clarify what is meant on that page in the Gemara? It will avoid a lot of future "debate".

Comment: What the Gemara means is that the Torah may only be broken up into the "paragraphs" that Moshe broke them up into. I.e. what you are referring to as "parsha". Thus, when one reads the weekly portion of the Torah (what you are referring to as "sidrah") it would have to conform to the parsha breaks. Thus, the answer to your question is that all sidrot (excepting Vayigash/Vayechi) begin/end at parsha breaks because the Talmud says that those are the only breaks we are allowed to make.

Comment: @DanF I forgot to ping you in my above comment. Also, see [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89877/13438) to [your question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87220/when-were-the-weekly-sidrot-torah-readings-organized) about when the sidrot were organized.

Comment: Thanks. That warrants a follow up question regarding the fast day reading.

Comment: @DanF You asked that, or something similar, [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78080/has-any-commentary-explained-why-the-torah-reading-for-fast-days-doesnt-begin-a?rq=1).